# Android Studio LogCat won't always output fields within a loop

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

I am logging the output of various parts of the route set by a Navigation app
Using exactly the same route each time, 10 instruction objects are generated 
I log various aspects of each instruction

However, if I choose log one field, that is generally empty, it sometimes leaves out certain iterations of the loop

here is my code for log 1

```
Log.d("qw", "NUMBER OF INSTRUCTIONS " + resp.getInstructions().size());
for (Instruction i:resp.getInstructions()) {
    Log.d("qw", "extra " + i.getExtraInfoJSON());
}
```

This should log the 'extra' field 10 x
it doesn't , it logs it only 6x

```
2020-02-19 00:48:04.045 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: NUMBER OF INSTRUCTIONS 10
2020-02-19 00:48:04.045 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {heading=251.34}
2020-02-19 00:48:04.045 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {}
2020-02-19 00:48:04.045 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {}
2020-02-19 00:48:04.045 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {exit_number=1, exited=true, turn_angle=1.76}
2020-02-19 00:48:04.045 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {exit_number=1, exited=true, turn_angle=2.81}
2020-02-19 00:48:04.045 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {last_heading=73.96885135138928}
```

If I now log two fields, including one that is always populated, like so

```
Log.d("qw", "NUMBER OF INSTRUCTIONS " + resp.getInstructions().size());
for (Instruction i: resp.getInstructions()) {

    Log.d("qw", "extra " + i.getExtraInfoJSON()); // heading | roundabout 

    Log.d("qw", "translation " + i.getTurnDescription(esTR)); // translation of 
}
```

now, all of the 10 instructions are logged

```
this is what is logged
2020-02-19 00:21:48.185 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: NUMBER OF INSTRUCTIONS 10
2020-02-19 00:21:48.185 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {heading=251.34}
2020-02-19 00:21:48.185 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: translation continue onto Clements Crescent
2020-02-19 00:21:48.185 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {}
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: translation turn left onto Samuel Place
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {}
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: translation turn right onto Herbert Road
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {}
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: translation turn left onto Laurence Street
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {}
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: translation turn right onto Bankwood Road
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {}
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: translation turn left onto Comries Road
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {}
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: translation turn right onto Bankwood Road
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {exit_number=1, exited=true, turn_angle=1.76}
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: translation At roundabout, take exit 1 onto Clarkin Road
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {exit_number=1, exited=true, turn_angle=2.81}
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: translation At roundabout, take exit 1 onto Clarkin Road
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: extra {last_heading=73.96885135138928}
2020-02-19 00:21:48.186 17624-17624/com.graphhopper.android D/qw: translation arrive at destination
```

Why am I experiencing this behaviour ?

Comment: if some logs are repeated again and again, so instead showing them all it groups together something like  I/chatty: uid=10085(your.package.name) roidJUnitRunner identical 3 lines

Comment: hmmm, ok if that's what's happening( I'm not seeing anything like (I/chatty: uid=10085(your.package.name) roidJUnitRunner identical 3 lines),  is there a way to force it not to do that ?

Comment: may be you need to clear the text from search filter and select "verbose" from dropdown

Comment: yes, using verbose , same thing occurs when no filter, and they all have the same tag

Comment: just try to add one incremented int in the message.

Comment: assign `resp.getInstructions()` to a variable first and use that variable. see if it makes any difference

Comment: @Waqar UlHaq - thanks, adding the increment works

Answer (score 0):

Solved : Adding an incremented field, in this case an index for each instruction causes the Logcat to print in 'each' case